# How to use cookies from Chrome in Advanced REST API client

Tags: rest

I have such problem:
Previously Advanced REST API client was integrated with browser and I could send request to my app if I was logged in my app. And now it is separated and it doesn't use session from browser.

How can I use cookies/session to send requests to my app without logging in???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, 
Against advanced Rest Api client I tried Postman, but Postman for using cookies from browser needs additional extension that called Postman Interceptor. it communicates with Postman and you can send requests.

Answer (score 12):

Install ARC cookie exchange from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-cookie-exchange/apcedakaoficjlofohhcmkkljehnmebp

Comment: Note: also you need to toggle on the XHR option when making a request in ARC

Comment: I installed it but it's still not working. Do I have something in addition? I don't see a Cookie header being set.

Comment: @displayname, yes, see comment above.